# Share on Facebook, use URL redirection in a pop up?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, social-networking

I've checked out the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) and implemented sharing on my site.

I have implemented a URL redirection like so:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup
  &href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer
```

When you click on the link on my website it opens as a new Facebook page and takes users away from my site. Is there a way using URL redirection to have it open in a popup? Or would I need to implement a JS solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaScript to open it as a popup.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Popup window code for Facebook 
    function newPopup(url) 
    {
        popupWindow = window.open
        (
    url,'popUpWindow','height=400,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes'
        )
        }
</script>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?http://www.geekdashboard.com&display=popup');">Click Here</a>
```

Change the URL as your requirement.